# Able to log the object property before its creation

Tags: javascript, object, order-of-execution

This is an example code to illustrate the situation.
In chrome dev tools a code like this doesn't log `undefined` but the data, and if i put `debugger;` or `alert()` before `console.log()` then it logs `undefined` as expected.
How to understand and explain this strange behaviour?

```
class aClass {
  constructor(){

  }
  aMethod(){
   console.log(this.anObject.theProperty);
   this.anObject.theProperty = 'set';
  }
  anotherMethod(){
    this.anObject = {
      someProperty:'someData'
    };
  }
}

var instance = new aClass;
instance.anotherMethod();    
instance.aMethod();
```

A simplified fragment of the real code that creates this behaviour is below, i didn't include the class which `this` refers. 
I couldn't find a way to reproduce the behaviour, but aybe you can give me advise?

Thank you.

```
    updateHandlesExternally(divWidth,divHeight,parentId){

            console.log('DW','DH',this.eventStore.dw,this.eventStore.dh,'NORW','NORH',norW,norH)

            var norW = divWidth*this.stateStore.s;
            var norH = divHeight*this.stateStore.s;

            this.eventStore.dw  = norW - this.stateStore.bb.width;
            this.eventStore.dh  = norH - this.stateStore.bb.height;

    }

    init(){

        var obj = this;

        obj.stateStore ={
          s:1,
          bb:{
            width:obj.bb.width,
            height:obj.bb.height,
            x:obj.bb.x,
            y:obj.bb.y,
            ox:obj.bb.x + obj.bb.width/2,
            oy:obj.bb.y + obj.bb.height/2
          }
        }
        obj.eventStore = {
            lastAngle : 0,
        };

    }
```

Comment: Make a code snippet using your example, and it'll output `undefined`.

Comment: I will share a screen shot.

Comment: Please don't share a screenshot, they're useless - please instead make a code snippet

Comment: Ok. i inspected that the event that calls `updateHandlesExternally` fires two times when i don't call `alert()` before `console.log()` that explains the situation because my log is crowded i didn't see the first call's log, but if i call `alert()` before `console.log()` the method call happens only one time and return `undefined`.
Is this question still relevant?
I also would like to know why it calls one time when i call `alert()` before `console.log()`.
The code is around 2000 lines and includes a library with modified source, thats why it is not easy to share.

Comment: In short words does `alert()` stops some code's execution?

Comment: [Yes](http://w3c.github.io/html/webappapis.html#dom-window-alert), it does.